# Could someone explain me this line?

Tags: c++, vector, typedef

Ok, here's one line in C++

```
typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
```

I understand, that this line creates an alias called vec_sz. But I can't understand why vector is used here??? What general has typedef and vector. I try to find out this whole evening, but I still don't understand.

Comment: You might later declare a variable `vec_sz count;` and store the size returned by your vector<double> in it. It's probably some kind of integer.  The person who wrote this code probably prefers the shortform vec_sz to be used instead of the full type declaration, and probably believes that if the type ever changed in future, changing the typedef in one place was the way to have the type be changed throughout her codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vec_sz` is now an alias for the data type used to represent the size of the `vector` (which is almost always `size_t`). So suppose you want to index elements in the vector, you'd use `vec_sz` as follows:

```
for(vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < some_vector.size(); ++i)
{
...
}
```

which (thanks to the `typedef`) is now equivalent to:

```
for(vec_sz i = 0; i < some_vector.size(); ++i)
{
...
}
```

You might wonder, "Why use `vec_sz`? Why shouldn't I just use `int`?". Well, this makes your code more portable and less prone to relying on your assumptions (which could be wrong).

Of course, it's better to access elements in vector through [iterators](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html).

Answer (score 2):

Classes can have typedefs inside of them:

```
class foo {
public:
  typedef int bar;
}

foo::bar my_int; // same as int my_int;
```

Vector has a typedef that corresponds to size_t

```
vector<double>::size_type my_int; // roughly the same as size_t my_int
                                  // implementation may not use size_t
```

That's a lot of typing and so you can typedef it again to make the line shorter:

```
typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
vec_sz my_int; // same as vector<double>::size_type my_int; which is the same as size_t my_int;
```

Answer (score 1):

Each vector-class (vector in your case) defines some unsigned integral type named size_type. Something like this:

```
template<class T> vector {
  typedef size_t size_type;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's type used in std::vector class for storing size. On many platforms and os'es this can differ, and using this type ensures that you will read its size properly.

For example, one could use int as its size type. However, if the vector's size type is unsigned int, when the vector exceeds maximum signed int size, strange results can happen.

Additional information can be found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types
As you can see, int is guaranteed to have at least 16 bytes, which can differ between operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

`size_type` is a *member typedef* of `std::vector<double>`.

```
namespace std {
    template <typename T> class vector {
    public:
        typedef __something size_type;
        size_type size() const;
    // ...
    };
}
```

The standard avoids specifying things like "the return type of `vector<T>::size()` is `unsigned int`, in case an implementation can support more elements in a vector than can be represented by the max value of `unsigned int`.  Instead, it specifies some implementation-defined member types, so the library can use whatever type makes the most sense, and user code can easily use that type.

Also, `vector<double>::size_type` and `vector<char>::size_type` could be different (though they're usually the same).

So the quoted code says "make another typedef `vec_sz` for the C++ library's type used for numbers of elements in vectors containing double".